# Why Visual Studio Ultimate Instrumentation C# profiling doesn't include called functions within same class?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiler

I'm using the Visual Studio 2010 profiler to try and find what functions within a certain project are taking up the most time.  These functions are within a different project than the main application which is referencing it, but it's included in the profiling Targets.  My issue is it profiles up to a certain function and then doesn't give me any profiling data of the functions called by it.  While it's great to know that the function itself is taking 14 seconds, I'm needing to know the time break down of the functions called by it.  These functions are all in the same class as the function it stops at, so I'm confounded as to why it doesn't continue to profile past this certain point.  Within the 'Caller / Callee' view it shows that no functions were called  by the function, when in actuality a lot of functions are called by it (thus the 14 second timing).

I tried turning off 'Enable Just My Code', turned off 'Exclude small functions' yet it still just mysteriously stops at this function.  Does anyone know any reasons why this would happen?

Comment: Is "optimize code" turned off in the project's build settings?

Comment: Yeah it's turned off in all of them.